# NPR radio story about spaceship with forbidden door

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Quite a few years ago my wife kids and I were driving through Cincinnati returning home from Alabama.  As usual they were asleep and as usual I had on Public radio.
I was listening to a radio sci-fi drama and as you might guess we got out of range before I could hear the end of it... not knowing the ending has **truly** bothered me for some 20 years.

The story was about a space ship that had sent the last vestiges of humanity into space.  Inside this spaceship was a door (gigantic) door that no one was allowed to open, and it meant being pushed out of an airlock if you even mentioned, attempted to open, or even questioned what was behind this door.
The voyage had lasted a thousand or so years, and our hero was discussing the "door", and was being interrogated as to why he was interested in the door. The some alarm sounded and the door started making noises.

That's when I lost the signal.  I have searched as far as I can to know how this story ended, and I'm hoping that someone here can either point me to the audio file, or at least tell me how it **ended**.

Comment: Sounds a bit like [Terminal Voyage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_Voyage), but I don't think NPR did a radio play about it.

Comment: Similar perhaps to Heinlein's Universe where it is forbidden to think there's any universe  outside of the ark ship? 
 https://www.oldtimeradiodownloads.com/sci-fi/x-minus-one/universe-1955-05-15

Comment: I'll wager a shiny pound coin that what was behind the door was "*the outside world and the whole spaceship was a gigantic con"*

Comment: Here is a list of NPR sci fi radio plays from 2000. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000X

Comment: Npr does replay episodes of x minus one/ dimension x so I suspect this was the adaptation of Universe (or a knock off of it)

Comment: It didn't help me, but SciFiMike's [Science Fiction Radio page](https://www.scifimike.com/sf-radio.html) has brief descriptions of most of the episodes of most of the series mentioned.  It didn't help me, but maybe you'll find something there.

Comment: @Cassfrank the audio files for 2000x  https://archive.org/details/2000x

Comment: I know that one of the public radio stations in Cincinnati definitely reran lots of older science fiction radio programs (including *X Minus One*) in the early 2000s, so it might well have been the older radio play.

Comment: I'm interested to see the outcome of this quesiton. The idea of a forbidden door is at least as old as *The Thousand and One Nights.* The idea has been reused at least as many times as the old Arabian tales had nights.

Comment: Here's a transcript of the x minus one Universe https://www.genericradio.com/show/HEQPMCAIQ adaptation.